# Empty textfield after button click nativescript vue

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, textfield

I am trying to empty a textfield after I sent the message filled in. The message gets sent to the database but after that it doesn't empty it.

Textfield:

```
<FlexboxLayout class="text-send">
      <TextField
        v-model="newMessage"
        id="try"
        class="body text-field"
        width="70%"
        @returnPress="onSendMessage()"
      ></TextField>

      <Button
        class="btn-secondary btn-design btn-next fas"
        text.decode=">"
        width="10%"
        @tap="onSendMessage()"
      />
    </FlexboxLayout>
```

sendMessage code:

```
onSendMessage() {
  if (this.newMessage != "") {
    let currentDate = Date()
    firebase
      .push("/messages/" + this.chatId, {
        message: this.newMessage,
        sender: this.getUserID,
        timestamp: currentDate,
      })
      .then(function (result) {
        console.log("created key: " + result.key); 
      });
  }
  this.newMessage = ""
},
```

This.newMessage = "", should clear the data, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try to move the this.newMessage = '' in your .then or log the result  of new message after your clear please to investigate further

Answer (score 0):

Move the `newMessage` within `.then()`. You can try debug by adding `console.log` after `newMessage` was cleared and see whats the output.

```js
onSendMessage() {
  if (this.newMessage != "") {
    let currentDate = Date()
    firebase
      .push("/messages/" + this.chatId, {
        message: this.newMessage,
        sender: this.getUserID,
        timestamp: currentDate,
      })
      .then(function (result) {
        console.log("created key: " + result.key); 

        this.newMessage = ""

      });
  }
},
```

Comment: In the .then() it is not able to call this. anything at all. If i put `console.log("new message: " + this.newMessage)` in the then(), it doesn't get shown in de terminal.
When updating it outside of the .then() it does update newMessage to nothing but doesn't update the page.